# I need to edit a widget, with no dashboard access

Tags: php, widgets

What the title says. There's a widget on a website that I need to edit, but I only have ftp access.

I've tried everything to try and locate where the template is for the specific widget I'm trying to edit (yes I tried Ctrl+Shift+F in sublime).

This is the widget that needs to be edited:

```
<div id="custom_html-5" class="widget_text et_pb_widget widget_custom_html">
    <h4 class="widgettitle">The Inside Edge Service</h4>
    <div class="textwidget custom-html-widget">
         <div class="testimonial-descript">
              <p>I know Mike is a very solid investor and respect his opinions very much. So if he says pay attention to this or that - I will.</p>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The theme being used is Divi. The widget is located inside Divi's sidebar module.

I am very desperate, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a text widget, I think.

If you need to modify title/content text then you need to modify in database (as you've no dashboard access*)

If you need to change div structure for that widget, then you code in child theme.

[*Note: if you got Database access then you can manage dashboard access too.]